# Formula to value when saving excel

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I need a formula to copy and replace a cell's formula to values, when the sheet is saved.

I have a `=today()` formula in cells C2:E2. It works, but the problem is when I reopen the file it will show that day, instead of showing the day the sheet was saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily with VBA:

ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Column).Value = Date

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a Workbook_BeforeClose [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook_events.aspx) that will replace your formula by its value:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
     Range("C2:E2").Value = Range("C2:E2").Value
     ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

This code has to be placed in `ThisWorkbook` object not as a `Module` macro.

**EDIT:**

Sorry I misread. If you want the replacement to be done when you save your workbook then the same applies but the code is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
     Range("C2:E2").Value = Range("C2:E2").Value
End Sub
```